# download file instead of opening in browser using struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I have written a file upload and download in struts2.
But while I download the `text.pdf` file that are opened in the browser page,
How to I download files instead of open in the browsers page?

```
<div class="block-fluid table-sorting clearfix">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table" id="tSortable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>S. No</th>
                <th>ACCOUNT NO</th>
                <th>FILE </th>
                <th>ACTION</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <s:iterator value="fileuploadlist" status="rowstatus" >
                <tr>                           
                    <td><s:property value="#rowstatus.index+1" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="fileupload_temp2" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="fileupload_filename"/></td>                                    
                    <td><s:a href="%{fileupload_filepath}" target="_blank" >download</s:a> </td>

                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This may be a browser specific setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I have uploaded the image that contain the struts configuration file.

Comment: Edit your question. Don't post code/conf as images.

Answer (score 2):

You can force downloading, but you have to do it *from the server side*: Implement your own endpoint (a servlet, for example) which returns this header along with the requested file:

```
content-disposition: attachment; filename="suggested-filename"
```

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple examples provided online for your query.

Please check the following links..

[File Download example -1](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/struts/sample-struts2-application-for-downloading-files)

[File Download example -2](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-download-file-example/)

And `target="_blank"` is used for creating a new tab, which is not required for your case.

Edit: Please show us your struts configuration, so that we can provide a much better answer.